# List of unique items from two lists with duplicates between each other

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to combine two lists to a single one, containing only unique elements:

```
log_file = ['warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot', 'normal_string',
            'invalid error', 'normal_string', 'invalid error']

warnings_list = ('warning CS', 'warning LNK', 'invalid')
error_list = ('cannot', 'error')

found_warnings = [message for message in log_file for i in warnings_list if i in message]
found_errors = [message for message in log_file for i in error_list if i in message]

found_warnings = list(set(found_warnings))
found_errors = list(set(found_errors))

total_unique_errors = list(set(found_errors + found_warnings))

print total_unique_errors
```

The output I'm  getting is correct:

```
['invalid error', 'warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot']
```

Is there any better way to do it?

**UPD #1:**
Also, I'm intersted if there any way to save number of unique errors or warnings? For example, if I want to get the same output as mentioned above, but also would like to have a way to check total errors/warnings number: `len(found_errors)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First convert the `log_file` entries to a set, to remove the duplicate entries, like this

   ```
   log_file = set(log_file)
   ```
2. Combine the errors and warnings list to a single tuple

   ```
   entries = errors_list + warnings_list
   ```
3. Then iterate the items to be checked, like this

   ```
   [item for item in log_file if any(entry in item for entry in entries)]
   ```

In short, your code can be written like this

```
>>> entries = error_list + warnings_list
>>> [item for item in set(log_file) if any(entry in item for entry in entries)]
['invalid error', 'warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot']
```

**Edit:** As per the updated question,

```
>>> log_file = set(log_file)
>>> warnings = [item for item in log_file if any(entry in item for entry in warnings_list)]
>>> errors = [item for item in log_file if any(entry in item for entry in error_list)]
>>> warnings
['invalid error', 'warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot']
>>> errors
['invalid error', 'warning CSS607: cannot']
>>> list(set(warnings + errors))
['invalid error', 'warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot']
```

If you can use `sets`, you don't have to convert to `list` and use `set` comprehension, like this

```
>>> warnings = {item for item in log_file if any(entry in item for entry in warnings_list)}
>>> errors = {item for item in log_file if any(entry in item for entry in error_list)}
>>> warnings
set(['invalid error', 'warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot'])
>>> errors
set(['invalid error', 'warning CSS607: cannot'])
>>> warnings | errors
set(['invalid error', 'warning CS1607:', 'warning CSS607: cannot'])
```

Comment: Thank you! 

It seems the right way to do it, but I'm also curious if there is a way to save a information about errors and warnings found (like a did it in my example)?

Thanks!

Comment: @silent Why do you want all of them to be lists? Can't they be sets?

Comment: I need to print each item to a text file after I will have total errors list. Not sure if there is a difference between a list or set in this case.

Comment: @silent Nope, you can use sets in that case... Please check my updated answer.